# Basis of span in $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

$$v_1 = (1, 0, 1, 0)^T, v_2 = (2, h, 2, h)^T, v_3 = (1, 1+h, 1, 2h)^T$$

and I am to find the basis of the span of $v_1, v_2, v_3$

So far I have set it up in a matrix in the form of

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & h & 1 + h \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & h & 2h
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and through Gaussian elimination I have come to the result

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & h & 1 + h \\ 
0 & 0 & h - 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Leading me to think that the Basis for this span is the set of the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ because of the linear dependence. Have I made some mistake here or completely misunderstood what the basis is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider the following cases

- for $h=1$ the first two columns vectors are liner independent thus $v_1$ and $v_2$ are a basis
- for $h=0$ the first and the third columns vectors are liner independent thus  $v_1$ and $v_3$ are a basis
- otherwise the first three columns vectors are liner independent thus $v_1$,$v_2$ and $v_3$ are a basis

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you (also) made row operations, which are not allowed here in the following sense:
For example $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is a basis of $\Bbb{R}e_1$ but $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ isn't a basis of $\Bbb{R}e_1$.

I would do the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & h & 1 + h \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & h & 2h
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & h & 1 + h \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & h & 2h
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & h & 1 - h \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & h & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So you have the following three cases

- $h=0$: The first and the third column form a basis
- $h=1$: The first and the second column form a basis
- Else: The three columns form a basis

Comment: Why should row operations not be allowed? They don’t change linear relations between columns.

Comment: To find the basis vectors row operation are allowed. Of course, column space change thus the basis is given by the correponding initial vectors.

Comment: @egreg I added an example how I meant it. Of course column operations are allowed if one remembers not to pick the column vectors but instead the corresponding initial vectors, as gimusi said. Sorry for the misleading phrasing.

Comment: The OP clearly refers to $v_1$ and $v_2$.